# Why did the chicken wear a snorkel?

Tags: hay-day

When I started playing HayDay, my Chickens wore snorkels, Pigs wore sunglasses, etc.

I found an image showing the snorkel on the chicken below:

[image: Chicken with Snorkel]

It has been removed/altered, and I no longer have any of these modifications on any of my animals (Cows, Chickens, Pigs or Sheep).

**Why** was it there and **how** can I get it back?

Comment: To get to the other side... Sorry :(

Comment: [Interesting Question](http://www.myfacewhen.net/uploads/2058-thinking.jpg)

Comment: @Lyrical Was waiting for something like that xD

Comment: sort of thing that gets your attention like the sheep question

Comment: Nice title!  [Listed](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9713/the-master-list-of-questions-which-really-need-context/9714#9714)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Hay Day wikia](http://hayday.wikia.com/wiki/Chicken) it was to celebrate their birthday:

> On July 10, 2013 (and the following year), to celebrate Hay Day's birthday, all animals were updated with new summer clothes and appearances. For the chicken, it's updated appearance includes a blue snorkel mask. On Oct 16, 2013, the chickens had carved, smiling pumpkins attached to their bodies for Halloween.

It is also in the [update logs](http://hayday.wikia.com/wiki/Version_history#Update_v1.11.47_.2810_July_2013.29)(v1.11.47):

> - Summer Theme: Your farm animals love the summer! How do you like their fun and exciting new looks? All your favorite farm animals in sun glasses, snorkels and Hawaiian shirts!

In the [next update](http://hayday.wikia.com/wiki/Version_history#Update_1.12.137_.2812_Sept_2013.29), it was removed:

> End of summer:
>
> - Reverted the summer clothing from the farm animals
> - Removed the exclusive summer decorations from the shop
> - Reverted the happy birthday loading screen back to normal

So you will not be able to bring it back, as it was a game update.

Comment: I was wrong. It wasn't only on the tenth of july, it was a whole update. The next update removed it. Therefor, you cannot bring it back like that.